# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC redirect in a custom AuthorizationHandler

Tags: .net-core-3.1, asp.net-authorization

In a ASP.NET Core 2 MVC app, I had a custom `AuthorizationHandler` that redirected blocked users back to the home page.

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsAllowedIpAddressRequirement requirement)
{
    // Cast the context resource
    if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext cxt)
    {
            // Failed!
            cxt.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Index", "Home", new { msg = "Your auth has failed." });
            context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
    ...
}
```

Since migrating to ASP.NET Core 3.1, the context is an object of class `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteEndpoint`, which has no `Result` property.

How can I redirect the user to a specific page?

Comment: same issue.. I have a subscription policy implemented with a Requirement similar to the op. Based on the type of subscription the user has I want to redirtect to a particular subscription page.. but how can this be done in net core3.1..?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and to solve it I changed to Filter (`IAsyncResourceFilter`) instead of Policy.

You can wrap your authorization logic into a policy and then invoke the IAuthorizationService and redirect anywhere/anytime you need.

Example:

```
public class MySampleActionFilter: IActionFilter
{
   public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {
       //if failed
       context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictonary(new
       {
           controller = "Your Controller",
           action = "Your Action"
       }));
   }
}
```

By the way, this is for .net Core 3 and above

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Mind including the code to check if it failed or not?

Comment: Failed in this case depends of your business rules

Comment: I learned a lot more since I had post thiisncomment

Answer (score 1):

if you want to user redirect to some page like login page, if user didn't has access, you could following below steps for fix it:

1. into `HandleRequirementAsync`  method

   ```
       if (Condition())
       {
           context.Succeed(requirement);
       }
       else {
           context.Fail();
       }
   ```

if user did has access, execute   `context.Succeed(requirement);` and if user didn't has access, execute   `context.Fail();`

2. into `startup.cs` => `ConfigureServices` method

   ```
   services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
   {
       options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
       options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
       options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
       options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
       options.SlidingExpiration = true;
   });
   ```

in line that we write

```
 options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
```

we appointment users after failing in `HandleRequirementAsync`  method for checking access, being redirected to controller 'home' controller  and 'login' actiion.

i'll hope my answer be useful for friends.

Comment: I don't think this satisfies the requirement at all. What the OP needs, and the boat which I am in is a method that previously existed of redirecting a user somewhere else if authorization fails.